# How can I get the sum of all list[1] inside of list of lists items using python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the sum of x in this type of list: `myList=[[y,x],[y,x],[y,x]`

Here is my code I have been trying:

```
myLists = [['0.9999', '2423.99000000'], ['0.9998', '900.00000000'], ['0.9997', '4741.23000000'], ['0.9995', '6516.16000000'], ['0.9991', '10.01000000'], ['0.9990', '9800.00000000']]
if chckList(myLists):
    floatList = []
    listLength = len(acceptibleBids)

    acceptibleBids0 = list(map(float, acceptibleBids[0]))
    acceptibleBids1 = list(map(float, acceptibleBids[1]))

    floatList.append(acceptibleBids0)
    floatList.append(acceptibleBids1)

    sumAmounts = sum(amount[1] for amount in floatList)
    print(sumAmounts)
    print(acceptibleBids)
```

I have run into many problems, but my current problem are listed below:
1. This list is the way I receive it, so the fact that they are all strings I have been trying to change them to floats so that I can the the sum(myList[1]) of each list inside myList.
2. The list ranges from 1 to 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
sum = 0
for pair in myLists:
    sum+= float(pair[1])

#of course, if there is something that can't
#be a float there, it'll raise an error, so
#do make all the checks you need to make
```

I'm unsure where `acceptibleBids` comes from in that code, but I'll assume it is a copy of `myList`, or something similar to it. The problem with your code is that `acceptibleBids[0]` is just `['0.9999', '2423.99000000']`. Similarly, `acceptibleBids[1]` is just `['0.9998', '900.00000000']`. So when end up with `acceptibleBids0` as `[[0.9999, 2423.99000000]]` and `acceptibleBids1` is similarly wrong. Then this makes `floatList` not be what you wanted it to be.

Edit: list comprehension works too, but I kinda like this way of looking at it. Either way, with list comprehension this would be `sum_floats = sum(float([pair[1]) for pair in myLists])`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *list comprehension*:

```
total = sum([float(x[1]) for x in myLists])
print(total) # 24391.39
```

Comment: This is perfect for what I am doing! Thank you, you helped a great deal :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will do:

```
>>> sum([float(x[0]) for x in myLists])
5.997
```